# select into single column from instead 4 different columns?

Tags: sql-server, select, case, multiple-columns

i am trying to instead haveing 4 different columns in case statment(Case_Close,Case_Open,Case_Comment,Case_Retrieve)
 to put all in single column, and not sure how to do that.
what i ahve till now is:

```
 select report_id,
    user_id,
    action_type,
    action_start,
    action_end ,
    CASE WHEN ACTION_END is null THEN  case ACTION_TYPE when 'CLOSE' then ACTION_START  end  END as Case_Close,
    CASE WHEN ACTION_END is null THEN  case ACTION_TYPE when 'OPEN' then GETDATE() end END as Case_Open,
    CASE WHEN ACTION_END is null THEN  case ACTION_TYPE when 'COMMENT' then GETDATE() end END as Case_Comment,
    CASE WHEN ACTION_END is null THEN  case ACTION_TYPE when 'RETRIEVE' then GETDATE() end END as Case_Retrieve

    from Table1
    order by report_id
```

and look like this:

```
report_id            user_id     action_type action_start            action_end              Case_Close              Case_Open               Case_Comment            Case_Retrieve
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
20122511549-621      621         CLOSE       2012-02-19 10:53:28.000 NULL                    2012-02-19 10:53:28.000 NULL                    NULL                    NULL
20122511549-621      621         OPEN        2012-02-05 11:05:49.000 2012-02-19 10:53:28.000 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
20132121098-621      621         OPEN        2013-02-12 10:09:08.807 2013-02-12 11:16:17.167 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
20132121098-621      621         COMMENT     2013-02-12 11:16:17.167 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017 NULL
201321814390-621     621         OPEN        2013-02-18 14:39:00.157 NULL                    NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017 NULL                    NULL
201322010148-707     707         OPEN        2013-02-20 10:01:48.693 2013-10-29 13:22:05.017 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
201322010148-707     707         RETRIEVE    2013-10-29 13:22:05.017 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017
2013222142012-621    621         OPEN        2013-02-22 14:20:12.327 NULL                    NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017 NULL                    NULL
2013225102516-707    707         OPEN        2013-02-25 10:25:16.790 2013-02-25 10:47:05.890 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2013225102516-707    707         OPEN        2013-02-04 13:48:38.293 2013-10-28 13:22:09.110 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL
201324134838-707     707         RETRIEVE    2013-10-28 13:22:09.110 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017
```

and what i need is to like this :

```
report_id            user_id     action_type action_start            action_end              Column_Action_End      
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
20122511549-621      621         CLOSE       2012-02-19 10:53:28.000 NULL                    2012-02-19 10:53:28.000
20122511549-621      621         OPEN        2012-02-05 11:05:49.000 2012-02-19 10:53:28.000 NULL                   
20132121098-621      621         OPEN        2013-02-12 10:09:08.807 2013-02-12 11:16:17.167 NULL                   
20132121098-621      621         COMMENT     2013-02-12 11:16:17.167 NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017
201321814390-621     621         OPEN        2013-02-18 14:39:00.157 NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017
201322010148-707     707         OPEN        2013-02-20 10:01:48.693 2013-10-29 13:22:05.017 NULL                   
201322010148-707     707         RETRIEVE    2013-10-29 13:22:05.017 NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017
2013222142012-621    621         OPEN        2013-02-22 14:20:12.327 NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017
2013225102516-707    707         OPEN        2013-02-25 10:25:16.790 2013-02-25 10:47:05.890 NULL                   
2013225102516-707    707         OPEN        2013-02-04 13:48:38.293 2013-10-28 13:22:09.110 NULL                   
201324134838-707     707         RETRIEVE    2013-10-28 13:22:09.110 NULL                    2013-12-26 14:55:12.017
```

i will appreciate if any1 can help me with that ?

Comment: Are you trying to fill in "action_end" when it's null? You can do that in the same column... using coalesce or isnull.

Comment: Thank you all guys i tried all of yours answers and all working for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select report_id,
    user_id,
    action_type,
    action_start,
    action_end ,
    CASE 
        WHEN ACTION_END is null AND ACTION_TYPE = 'CLOSE' then ACTION_START
        WHEN ACTION_END is null AND ACTION_TYPE IN ('OPEN', 'COMMENT', 'RETRIEVE') then GETDATE()
        ELSE NULL 
    END as Column_Action_End

from Table1
order by report_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine your case statements into one and have two conditionals in each `WHEN` clause:

```
SELECT 
    report_id,
    user_id,
    action_type,
    action_start,
    action_end,
    CASE 
        WHEN ACTION_END is null and ACTION_TYPE = 'CLOSE' then ACTION_START 
        WHEN ACTION_END is null and ACTION_TYPE = 'OPEN' then GETDATE()
        WHEN ACTION_END is null and ACTION_TYPE = 'COMMENT' then GETDATE()
        WHEN ACTION_END is null and ACTION_TYPE = 'RETRIEVE' then GETDATE()
    END as Column_Action_End
FROM Table1
ORDER BY report_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested case expression:

```
Select report_id, user_id, action_type, action_start, action_end ,
    Case When ACTION_END is null
         Then Case When ACTION_TYPE = 'CLOSE' Then ACTION_START
                   When ACTION_TYPE IN ('OPEN','COMMENT', 'RETRIEVE') Then GETDATE() 
              --Else ... (if you need else part for sub case expression) 
              End
    --Else ...(if you need else part for main Case expression)
    End As Column_Action_End
From Table1
Order by report_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just coalesce to check for action_end being null.

If there are only 4 action types and is not a nullable column then you can just check for "CLOSE"...

```
select report_id,
    user_id,
    action_type,
    action_start,
    coalesce(action_end,case when ACTION_TYPE = 'CLOSE' then ACTION_START else getdate() end) as action_end
from Table1
```

Otherwise, you'll have to check for all 4...

```
select report_id,
    user_id,
    action_type,
    action_start,
    coalesce(action_end,case when ACTION_TYPE = 'CLOSE' then ACTION_START when ACTION_TYPE in ('OPEN','COMMENT','RETRIEVE') then getdate() end) as action_end
from Table1
```

Comment: Thank you sam yi, that help me even bit more